# Non-negative Linear Span of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

I would like to understand if there is a common concept of a `linear span' of a set of vectors which are combined with non-negative multipliers.

I know that usual definition of the span of a set of vectors as follows [[wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span):

$\operatorname{span}(S) =  \left \{ {\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i \Big| k \in \mathbb{N}, v_i  \in S, \lambda _i  \in \mathbf{K}} \right \}.$

Is there a commonly used name for a span when $\lambda _i  \in R^+$ (positive real numbers) so that I can study this further? I cannot find much material in this area.

Ultimately, I am interested if there is a way to distinguish between matrices (or collections of vectors) that have full rank even if only positive multipliers are permitted.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have is a [convex cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone).

A cone is a set closed under positive scaling. A convex cone is a cone which is also closed under convex combinations.

Comment: Wow. That was so quick. I'm amazed/disappointed that I never came across that in hours of googling. Thanks very much!

Comment: You'll find it discussed at length in books on convex analysis and/or convex optimization